# Can i integrate two spring mvc project jar to war (Maven Build)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, build

Example: I have two project

1. ChildProject
2. ParentProject

Two project making using spring mvc. I want to integrate child project jar into parent project or child project `war` into parent project where ParentProject can access ChildProject `component` (like `service`, dao) and also view return mechanism will be specified. please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using maven. Follow below steps

1. Create a parent project with pom as packaging.
2. Create a `maven module` with parent as the one created in step 1. This is your core module where the common classes are. Define the packaging as `JAR`
3. Create another `module` with parent as the one created in step 1 . Then add dependency of the maven module we have created in step 2 to the `pom.xml` file of this module. So that all classes available in step 2 module will be available in step 3 module. The packaging for this module will be `war`.

Dependency add as below:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com</groupId>
            <artifactId>step2module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: lets again clear. Two project are spring mvc not a common classes or simple java file. where include all component of spring mvc in the project(ChaildProject) and this project will make a jar and ParentProject will be Inject some component of ChaildProject.